# F-curves disappeared but keyframes still work

Tags: video-sequence-editor, keyframes, graph-editor, dopesheet, fcurves

Perhaps another basic question about a mysterious disappearance. I am using Blender to edit video, and my F-curves have vanished. The keyframes are still visible and apparently functional in the keyframe editor, and a post on reddit suggests that I might have pushed an action down (?) whatever that means. There is an action (SceneAction.001) visible in the NLA editor, but there is nothing to see in the Action Editor.

Screenshots of the Action Editor, Dope Sheet, and NLA Editor below.

[image: Dope sheet]

[image: Action editor]

[image: NLA Editor]

Any pointers would be very much appreciated!

Comment: At the moment it looks like you have two screenshots of the dope sheet instead of one of the action editor.  Based on looking at the NLA editor it appears you have not turned it into a strip (because I still see a vv button).  Also, you might want to include a screenshot of the fcurves window.  There is also a pointer icon in the bottom of the fcurves window (next to the ghost icon) that will show fcurves even for non-selected items.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have turned it into an NLA strip, you have to select the strip in the NLA editor and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to begin editing the action in that strip.  One problem is that if you add keyframes outside the boundaries of the strip they will not affect the object.  There are other complications surrounding the strip extrapolation settings.

Alternately, you should be able to "undo" the stripification by selecting the object and using the dope sheet's Action Editor mode to assign its primary action to the one that was there before the stripification (make sure you are not tabbed into the strip or your change will affect the strip instead of the primary action).  It's the combo box left of the Push Down button.  At that point the object will have a primary action AND an NLA track with strip. You can delete the NLA track by selecting the track in the NLA editor and using the <kbd>x</kbd> to delete the track.

Comment: Thank you! Added some images - does that look like what you'd expect prior to undoing the stripification? I am not sure I have successfully located the combo box on the left of the Push Down button.